# jitpack.io - failure to resolve

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I'm trying to import a [library](https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView) using [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io). Here's my top-level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and here's my app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
    compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.0.6'

}
```

and I keep getting : `Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.0.6` without any additional information.

I've also tried with a sffuix as advised by the library's auther:

```
compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.0.6@aar'
```

Comment: check if you are working in offline mode

Answer (score 1):

Add your repository in app/build.gradle like below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }

}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.domain.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1/bolts-android-1.2.0.jar')
    compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.0.6'

}
```

Comment: i have tried to add this dependency it working fine for me.

Comment: I tried it now on new empty (templated) project , and fully updated studio/SDK - still no change.

Comment: @WaleedSarwar The repo is just added in the top level file as reported in the question.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti yes i noticed but some time it didn't work on top level file.So that's why i added it in project specific build.gradle.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks correct in your Gradle files. Your gradle plugin must not be picking up the JitPack repository for some reason.

See if you can resolve the JitPack test library:

compile 'com.github.jitpack:android-example:1.0.4'

If this cannot be resolved then it must be a configuration issue with your IDE / Gradle plugin / Machine.

Comment: ideed test libarary fails as well. machine/IDE are fully accessible to to world (android studio preforms self updating successfuly), no proxy defined and gradle in **not** in offline mode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I **update** and reconfigure my **IDE and my JDK** version (to **jdk 8**, you can set it on build options)

Then I followed the basic instructions (add JitPack repo in build.gradle on allprojects and the lib)

Also ensure that your min SDK doesn't be smaller than the declared in the lib

Answer (score 0):

I have a library project which depends on a library served from jitpack. In my case, adding the following to my library's `build.gradle` resolved the issue:

```
allprojects { p ->
    p.repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure add  maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } as the first respository. I am using android studio 3.3 and have the same issue. for some reason libraries in jitpack are fetched from google and jcenter and cant locate it. re-order the repos fix this for me hope its helpful to someone

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Open **settings.gradle** file and add the below line inside repositories (as shown in above picture)

```
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
```

And **remove** below code from **project's build.gradle** file

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}}
```